# How can I put bash script in C program

Tags: c, bash, shell

I have shell scripts and I need to run that continuous work in background.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (; ;) {
            system("./dup -r /root/duptest/");  
            sleep(60);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's working and run every minute.

**First question:** How can I run this background(like & --> ./dup ... &) without put &.

**Second question:** How can I put shell codes in C source codes? 
I found this, Do I need to put `\n\` for all lines? It's so hard for edit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
echo \"hello\" \n\
echo \"how are you\" \n\
echo \"today\" \n\
"

int main()
{
system(SHELLSCRIPT);
return 0;
}
```

**Third question:** How can I use shell parameter in C, like this:

```
./dup.exe -r /blablabla...
```

mean

```
 system("./dup -r /blablabla");
```

I need to use $1 $2 parameter with compiled C program.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Look for "how to make a process as deamon process in UNIX" Although daemon process is a overkill for your requirement, you can perform steps until the process is running according to your requirements
Question 3: You need to have command line arguments, check about that. Your main should look like `main(int arg_count, char *args_vector[]){...}` and in that you can access each command line argument as an array element

Answer (score 1):

Q1: use `fork()` and don't wait on the child's PID.

Q2: C and C++ will concatenate adjacent string literals, like so:

```
static const char script[] =
"echo hello\n"
"echo how are you\n"
"echo today"
;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  puts(script);      // so you can see what it looks like 
  // system(script); // <-- uncomment this line to actually run it.
  return 0;
}
```

Q3: use the `argc` and `argv` parameters to `main()` to build the command line you want to execute.